# Getting java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException , when trying to create zip file using java NIO 2 on MAC

Tags: java, io, nio

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.FileSystem;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ZipFileSystem {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:///sample.zip");
      Map<String,String> options = new HashMap<>();
      options.put("create","true");
      FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, options);
  }
}
```

I have this java simple code , when i try to run this on MAC, getting below exception, am I missing anything?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /sample.zip
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:116)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:117)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:326)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:276)
    at ZipFileSystem.main(ZipFileSystem.java:14)
```

Comment: Do you have write access to `/sample.zip`?

Comment: And to the root directory?